# C# DllImport Inconsistency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll, nunit

I am testing that I am using the correct dll interface for a ThirdParty.dll but using a mocked unmanaged dll in some unit tests. The ThirdParty.dll is imported using DllImport("ThirdParty.dll") inside the production code. The mock dll is placed in the same directory as the NUnit test code, the working directory of the command line set to the same directory as the Test Dll and mock dll, and then NUnit is called with a full path.

Example:

TestDirectory contains:

- Test.dll
- nunit.framework.dll
- pnunit.framework.dll
- ThirdParty.dll
- and some other dependencies.

and the following is called:

```
C:\TestDirectory>ProgFiles\NUnit\nunit-console-x86.exe Test.dll /config:Release /framework:net-4.0
```

On our development machines the mock version of ThirdParty.dll is picked up fine and our tests pass but when we put the same code and directory structure on the customer computer it picks up the real installed version of the dll instead, which we also have installed on our dev machines but gets blocked by the mock one during unit tests.

I'm aware of the Search Order used by Windows, but I think that in both instances the DLL should be found in step 1 "The directory from which the application loaded.". I'm also aware of picking up the same name DLL if it is in memory, but I believe this applies if it is in the same process memory, which it should not be.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could check or what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Weird. Usually the Search Order used by windows (Local dir, path and System32) works fine. I suggest you create a unit test that shows the current directory and check if the dll is there. If it isn't the same path of NUnit I would also test putting the dll in the same directory of NUnit.

Comment: I tried putting dlls in the same path as NUnit on my machine and they don't get found.

Comment: If you put a Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) which  path appears?

Comment: I can try that but unfortunately it takes a 2 day minimum to send code to the customer so I really need to stock up on possible tests.

Comment: Do a local test to check how it behaves in your machine. It can save you some time.

Comment: Sure "directory from which the application loaded" is searched first.  But of course in the case of a unit test that's the NUnit install directory.  It is very unclear how the DLL is found, probably by accident through the default working directory.

Comment: It doesn't seem to pick up dlls in the nunit directory first. I put one there and it wasn't picked up at all.

Comment: I think nunit itself may be clouding the issue here actually if dlls in the nunit directory aren't picked up by the tests.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be related to the way NUnit sets the working directory now: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=multiAssembly&r=2.6.3 and possibly the basepath/privatebinpath/etc arguments and possibly evening the shadowing http://nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3 . I'm home now but I'll check soon to see if I can change the way NUnit works.

Comment: I could take advantage of the "dll already in memory" aspect to override the Search Order and use an explicit "LoadLibrary" call in my NUnit test code to load the Mock dll before running the tests. That should fix the problem and make the test more specific about what I want to actually run.

Answer (score 0):

The search order for dynamic link libraries can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(VS.85).aspx). It's always the same, but it does depend on operating system settings, so with two different machines with different settings, you may get different results.

Comment: That was what I was referring to when I said step 1 "The directory from which the application loaded." which is the top step in the DllImport section. I am not using Windows Store Apps, nor LoadLibraryEx so those don't apply. In this case it should always pick up the dlls in the startup path first it seems but isn't.

Comment: Yes, but step 1 is not the first step (don't blame me, I did not write the document) :)

Comment: But the only previous step that I can see is checking if the dll is already loaded into memory, which I said that it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [fusion log viewer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to get a more detailed view into how your assembly is being found.  The viewer will list all paths your application is searching to load an assembly and where they were found.  This always give me an answer when I have unexpected DLL dependency problems.

Comment: Oh. I thought this looked good when I saw the comment walking to my car. I may still keep this in mind for future though.